# JSP - Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value" attributes

Tags: jsp

I am using struts1.1. When i redirect to one jsp file, i got the following exception. I cannot figure out where the error is.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/jobcard/JobCardAdd.jsp(908,3) Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value" attributes
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:39)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:405)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:86)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseParam(Parser.java:861)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1813)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1069)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseInclude(Parser.java:897)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1572)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1802)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1069)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1573)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1802)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1069)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1573)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:211)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:155)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:303)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
- ERROR Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
```

Comment: you should have posted the code snippet too

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I fixed this error by changing the following include tag as single tag version.

Before:

```
<jsp:include page="..."></jsp:include>
```

I changed like this,

```
<jsp:include page="..."/>
```

Now i did not get this type of exception.

Comment: If you read the stacktrace back, you would have seen that it was at its own already the answer :) Particularly since the lines with `parseOptionalBody` (note **Optional**) and then `parseParam`. Good that you figured/fixed it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I did not end tag properly. like below.

`<jsp:include page="..."`>

I have changed it to

```
<jsp:include page="..."/>
```

This fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't close the tag in the same line, you need to have a `<jsp:param name="someName" value="someValue" />` within `<jsp:include></jsp:include>`

Answer (score 2):

This error also happened in my project after a migration from weblogic to tomcat server

actually you can close the tag in a different line if you have `<jsp:param  name="xxx" value="yyy" />`

also what my Tomcat Server didn't like is that i have comments so i just deleted them and then it worked

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/myJsp.jsp" flush="true">
     <jsp:param name="formName" value="someValueForm" />    <!-- it indicated the form to use -->
     <jsp:param name="someFunction" value="someFunction" />    <!-- a comment here --> </jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I gave comments inside `<jsp:include>` tag. When I removed the comments from that block, it worked.

```
<!-- comment supported here -->
<jsp:include page="/jsp/include/productAttributePopUp.jsp" >
  <!-- comment not supported here -->
  <jsp:param name="showProdClassification" value="true"/> <!-- comment not supported here -->
</jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to change this:

```html
<jsp:forward page='redirect.jsp'>
</jsp:forward>
```

to this:

```html
<jsp:forward page='redirect.jsp'/>
```